# Solution of differential equation using Differential transform method

Tags: differential-equations, recursion

```
U[0]=0
For[k=0,k<=n,k=k+1,
 Print[
  k(k+1)Y[k+1]+2(k+1) Y[k+1]-(2 (Pi)^(k+1))/Factorial[k]  Cos[(k Pi)/2]+Pi^(k+1)/Factorial[k-1] Sin[((k-1)Pi)/2],
  "=",
  0] (*prints all components *)
 ]
```

Using above code in Mathematica we generate individual components in `Y[k]` form.
Please can any one suggest me to write a recursive Mathematica code, so that it uses initial conditions
and generates an all-numerical answer?

Comment: Your question isn't so easy to understand, please provide Mathematica code. What is the recursion-formula you want to evaluate? The function you are looking for is `RSolve`

Comment: Your equation is not a recurrence! It only contains `Y[k+1]`, but no other `Y`. Therefore, you may solve your equation, using `Solve` for `Y[k+1]` and then replace `k->k-1`this gives you the formula for `Y[k]`

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
RSolve[k (k + 1) Y[k + 1] + 2 (k + 1) Y[k + 1] - (2 (Pi)^(k + 1))/Factorial[k] Cos[(k Pi)/2] + Pi^(k + 1)/Factorial[k - 1] Sin[((k - 1) Pi)/2] == 0, Y, k]
```